# Python: converting a list of tuples to a list of dicts

Tags: python, json, d3.js, bundle-layout

I'm trying to mess with [this D3 visualization](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/7607999): (its code is [here](https://gist.github.com/mbostock/7607999))

[image]

However, I'm having trouble trying to get my data in the correct format.

The data (for reference) has to be in the format:

```
[
{"name":"something 1","size":number 1,"imports":["thing 1","thing 2","thing 3","thing 4","thing 5","thing 6"]},
{"name":"something 2","size":number 2,"imports":["thing 1","thing 2","thing 3","thing 4","thing 5"]}
]
```

Now, my data (as of now) is in the format (it was gathered using nltk):

```
[('would', 'MD'), ('said', 'VBD'), ('like', 'IN'), ('man', 'NN')]
```

Using defaultdict, I was able to convert the data using these lines:

```
pos = [('would', 'MD'), ('said', 'VBD'), ('like', 'IN'), ('man', 'NN')]
d = defaultdict( list )
for a, b in pos:
    d[b].append(a)
d = [ {b, d[b]} for b in d ]
```

to:

```
[
{'MD': ['would']}, 
{'NN': ['man']}, 
{'IN': ['like']}, 
{'VBD': ['would']}
]
```

I'm not quite sure how to proceed or how to get it in the correct format. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

EDIT: I should've been more clear; my expected output is something like:

```
[
{'name': 'man', 'POS':['MD']}
]
```

Comment: What's the expected output with your data?

Comment: You don't indicate what mapping you want to the final form.  is "something 1" suppose to be "MD"?  is "thing 1" to be "would"?  What is "number 1" supposed to be?

Comment: Could you update your input and output data to match? Right now, you're input data doesn't look anything like your output data.

Comment: Yeah, I know. I've been trying to do that for a while. But the input comes straight from an nltk function. I'm not sure how to modify the list of tuples to incorporate the 'name' and 'pos' stuff.

Comment: Your expected result is still not completely clear but I updated my answer based on your last edit.

Comment: Well, my ultimate goal is to get something like the 'flare-imports.json' file that's located at the github link.

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT**

```
oldList = [('would', 'MD'), ('said', 'VBD'), ('like', 'IN'), ('man', 'NN')]
newList = [{'name':a, 'POS':[b]} for a,b in list]

newList == [{'name': 'would', 'POS': ['MD']}, {'name': 'said', 'POS': ['VBD']}, {'name': 'like', 'POS': ['IN']}, {'name': 'man', 'POS': ['NN']}]
```

---

To convert to a list of dictionaries:

```
list = [('would', 'MD'), ('said', 'VBD'), ('like', 'IN'), ('man', 'NN')]
newlist = []
for a,b in list:
    newlist.append({a:b})

newlist == [{'would': 'MD'}, {'said': 'VBD'}, {'like': 'IN'}, {'man': 'NN'}]
```

Or to add each tuple to one dictionary:

```
list = [('would', 'MD'), ('said', 'VBD'), ('like', 'IN'), ('man', 'NN')]
newlist = {a:b for a, b in list}

newlist == {'said': 'VBD', 'like': 'IN', 'would': 'MD', 'man': 'NN'}
```

Comment: you could do `for (a,b) in list:` and skip the `[0]`

Comment: It's best to avoid using `list` as a variable name, since it's a built-in.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```
[{k, v} for k, v in list]
```

Comment: this creates a set containing `k` and `v` for each pair in `list`. is that what you expect it to do?